# Regular expression - Negative look-ahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

I'm trying to use Perl's negative look-ahead regular expression 
to exclude certain string from targeted string. Please give me your advice.

I was trying to get strings which do not have -sm, -sp, or -sa.

REGEX:

```
hostname .+-(?!sm|sp|sa).+
```

INPUT

```
hostname 9amnbb-rp01c
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-ra01c
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-sa01c
hostname 9amnbb-sa01
hostname 9amnbb-aaa-sa01c
```

Expected Output:

```
hostname 9amnbb-rp01c              - SELECTED
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-ra01c   - SELECTED 
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-sa01c
hostname 9amnbb-sa01
hostname 9amnbb-aaa-sa01c
```

However, I got this actual Output below:

```
hostname 9amnbb-rp01c              - SELECTED
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-ra01c   - SELECTED
hostname 9tlsys-eng-vm-r04-sa01c   - SELECTED
hostname 9amnbb-sa01
hostname 9amnbb-aaa-sa01c          - SELECTED
```

Please help me.

p.s.: I used [Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/#install)
to visualize my result.

Answer (score 4):

Move the `.+-` inside of the lookahead:

```
hostname (?!.+-(?:sm|sp|sa)).+
```

Rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/OuSwOLHhEy

Your current expression is not working properly because when the `.+-` is outside of the lookahead, it can backtrack until the lookahead no longer causes the regex to fail.  For example with the string `hostname 9amnbb-aaa-sa01c` and the regex `hostname .+-(?!sm|sp|sa).+`, the first `.+` would match `9amnbb`, the lookahead would see `aa` as the next two characters and continue, and the second `.+` woudl match `aaa-sa01c`.

An alternative to my current regex would be the following:

```
hostname .+-(?!sm|sp|sa)[^-]+?$
```

This would prevent the backtracking because no `-` can occur after the lookahead, the non-greedy `?` is used so that this would work correctly in a multiline global mode.

Comment: Is negative lookahead necessary for this??

Comment: @Rudie: Probably not, but an expression without lookahead would be more complicated.

Comment: The second regular expression 'hostname .+-(?!sm|sp|sa)[^-]+?$' matches 'hostname a-b-sm-c' and it shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

The following passes your testcases:

```
hostname [^-]+(-(?!sm|sp|sa)[^-]+)+$
```

I think it is a little easier to read than F.J.'s answer.

To answer Rudy: the question was posed as an exclusion-of-cases situation. That seems to fit negative lookahead well. :)